# Deriving the series for federal funds rate expectations using federal funds futures

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, yield-futures

I am trying to derive the monthly series from 2000-2019 of the expectations of federal funds rate based on federal funds futures.

How should I proceed? Where to look? Is it possible?

Comment: It is not as straightfoward as you may think https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18890/how-does-one-estimate-the-probability-of-the-fed-increasing-its-benchmark-rate-b?rq=1

Comment: You are correct, cannot access historical data.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're looking for - expectations are for future events but you're asking about the past. 

Market expectations of future rate movements vary; the expectation of a cut a month before a meeting date could turn into an expectation of a hike a week before the same date.

Comment: To be more precise, I am trying to derive the series of l expectations based on fed funds futures in the past. For example, based on futures what did the market expect in January 2000 and so on up till the latest date.